# Where to place my loop for better results in Client-Server architecture in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a client server architecture in Java in which I need to place a loop.
I've spent some time to think about where to put this loop, but anywhere I tried it did not get the result expected.

Here is my client.java :

```
public class Client {
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // set up server communication
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 1234);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        System.out.println("Enter pin : ");
        String password = scanner.next();

        // send PIN to server
        out.println(password);
        out.flush();

        // get response from server
        String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);

        scanner.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Here is my server.java :

```
public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket server;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        // Listen for client requests:
        String request = in.readLine();
        while (request != null) {

            // check PIN, send result
            boolean pinCorrect = checkPin(request);
            out.println(pinCorrect ? ":)" : ":(");
            out.flush();
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

I need to repeat this process if the user does not enter exactly 4 digits, so I've been thinking of a `do{}while(pinSize != 4)` loop.

But when I place it in the Server I always have the wrong output `":)" or ":("` instead of just `"Pin must be  4 digits"`, then I tried to put in the Client part, but this time I always had the possibility to enter only one pin so the loop did not work that much.

Actually this is some code I would put into my loop:

```
if (pinSize != 4) {
      System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Checking...");
    }
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Where in the server do you put the `loop`? If you do not open a new connection for each request, you must add some method of learning when a new character is part of the previous PIN or it is the beginning of the new one.

Comment: When you say repeat the process, do you mean have the server listen for next input again? If so, on each new connection, spawn a new thread that will handle that connection so your server can go back to listening for more?

Comment: And how you can get the output `"Pin must be 4 digits"` if you do not print it anywhere in your code?

Comment: @SJuan76 I put it just before the `while (request != null)` loop and end it right after it. All the `close();` are not in my loop. Is that correct ?

Comment: @SJuan76 in my edit, I've put the code I should insert into my loop, but it is commented since the I am trying to think about the loop first.

Comment: @StuWhyte I mean, when you see the code right now, it just asks a user to enter a pin code and then print if good or not. What I want to do is adding a condition on what the user enter, if he does not enter 4 digits, it has to ask again to enter a pin with 4 digits. But I am wondering if this loop needs to go on the Client part or Server part.

Comment: Add a condition to your scanner input, if the user has not entered 4 digits, do not send it to the server?

Comment: @StuWhyte it may be a valid option (+1) but it is also limited (if tomorrow you accept 5 digits integer then you will need to change the client)

Comment: If you only have a small amount of sizes the pin could be, just check the size and if its not an acceptable size as them to retype. Or if you have many lengths the pin could be, ask the user to first input the PIN length, and then the pin?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Actually there is no need to ask them the size of the pin. It'll be always 4 digits. But what you mean is adding a `if(pinSize != 4){ system.exit()}else{ do the thing...}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the check in client side code. For more info read inline comments.

- Fist use `nextLine()` in place of `next()` to read a whole line at a time.
- Validation check for password along with its length check

Here is the modified client side code. Please incorporate the changes.

```
    ...
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    System.out.println("Enter pin : ");
    String password = null;

    // 4 digits pattern
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}");

    while (true) {
        password = scanner.nextLine();
        int pinSize = password.length();
        if (pinSize == 4) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(password);
            if (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("Checking " + password);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Pin must be 4 digits");
        }
    }

    // send PIN to server
    out.println(password); 
    ...
```